# Okhttp JSON Parsing

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm trying to parse a Json data with the following code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusServices")
                .method("GET", null)
                .addHeader("AccountKey", "XXXX==")
                .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
                .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

The two errors that I'm facing are:

```
error: cannot find symbol method newBuilder()
```

and

```
unhandled exception error for .execute();.
```

Comment: you should use okhttpclient like this: `OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();`

Comment: I tried this and now the error is 'error: cannot find symbol class Builder'

Comment: what are you library imports for Okhttp

Comment: Did you tried the answer below? Also read the documentation provided.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://square.github.io/okhttp/ you just need to do:

`OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();`